# Input value to partially match item in array and return true

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I am currently working on a form where users can check if we deliver to their area by inputting their postcode. I have a working code if the input value partially matches "E1" but I need this to work if the value partially matches "E1, E2, E3 all the way to E18.

Eg. if a user inputs E2 4EJ, this returns true.

The code I am currently working is below. Any advice on what I need to change will be much appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First half of your postcode...">
    <button type="submit" value="Search">Submit</button> 
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(){
    var postcode = $('#searchForm input').val();  
    if (postcode.indexOf('E1') == 0) {
        $('#result').html('Yes, we deliver!');
    } else {
        $('#result').html('Sorry, we don't deliver!');
    }
    return false;
});
```

**Code I'm playing about with**

```
 var postcodes = ["E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10", "E11", "E12", "E13", "E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18"];
```

**EDIT**

After taking the correct answer below, my final code was:

```
var postcodes = ["E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10", "E11", "E12", "E13", "E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18"];

$('#searchForm').submit(function(e){
    var postcode = $('#searchForm input').val().toUpperCase();
    var postcodeAreaDeliverable = false;

    $.each( postcodes, function( index, value ) {
        if (postcode.match("^" + value)) {
            postcodeAreaDeliverable = true;
        }
     });

     if (postcodeAreaDeliverable) {
         $('#result').html('Yes, we deliver!');
     } else {
         $('#result').html('Sorry, we dont deliver!');
     }
return false;
});
```

Comment: The code you're working on is just an array. Maybe you can think about how you'd iterate through the array...

Comment: Ok so I'll probably need to use $.each to go through each item in the postcodes var and then work out if the input value partially matches what is in the var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate each postcode and look for a match.  If there is a match display the positive message,otherwise display the negative message:

```
var postcodeAreaDeliverable = false;
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  if (obj.match("^" + value) {
    postcodeAreaDeliverable = true;
  }
});
if (postcodeAreaDeliverable) {
  $('#result').html('Yes, we deliver!');
} else {
  $('#result').html('Sorry, we don't deliver!');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain what the code does rather than regurgitating a solution. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I had to leave the building in a hurry.  Posted what was there.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to adapt this to my needs and it works perfectly.